# DHCP Configuration for Windows Deployment Services

Tags: windows, dhcp, wds

I have Windows Deployment Services (WDS) currently running on one of my servers (within a domain of course). I have another machine running as a DHCP server, which is outside of the domain.

I don't seem to be able to find anywhere what settings I need to configure on the DHCP server in order for clients to find the WDS server. Google seems to continue to return results about running a DHCP server and a WDS server on the same machine (port conflicts, etc).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

open a *netsh* prompt:
dhcp server \\*servername*
add optiondef 60 PXEClient STRING 0 comment="Option added for PXE support"
set optionvalue 60 STRING PXEClient
set optionvalue 66 STRING *WDS_SERVER_IP*

Alternatively you can set options 66 and 67; but this will not use the PXE server, it will simply specify where to find the boot com file, and you will not get a menu of the different options specified in the WDS Console.

Answer (score 4):

You need to add Option 66, and Option 67 (Boot Server and Boot Filename).

Set the Boot IP to the IP address of the WDS server (if you specify a DNS server you can also use the hostname).

Set the Boot Filename to `boot\x86\wdsnbp.com`

A screenshot of our DHCP settings are below:

[image: DHCP settings for WDS]
<sub>(source: [41085.org](http://www.41085.org/WDSDHCP.png))</sub>

[See here](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-vista/cc766320(v=ws.10)?redirectedfrom=MSDN#BKMK_ConfiguringWDS) for more information (look for `Known issues with configuring Windows Deployment Services`).

We are using Server 2008 WDS, which provides a GUI screen where you can select the image you want to install after the intial boot. I've never used earlier versions of WDS so I don't know how they operate.