# WDS+DHCP+PXE in vSphere 6

Tags: dhcp, vmware-vsphere, pxe-boot

I have a Windows Server 2012R2 virtual machine running (vm1) on host1. with two networks. The first network is for normal production traffic and the second one is configured for DHCP/PXE. When I create a new VM (vm2) and place it on the PXE network, then boot, vm2 says, "No DHCP or proxyDHCP offers were received."

I have verified the following:
- The VMs are on the same host
- The DHCP server is authorized in AD
- The the DHCP server has option 60
- The physical port is a trunk and PortFast is enabled
- The Windows firewall is disabled

What am I missing here?

Thanks.

Comment: Is the server VM connected to each virtual switch for each physical NIC? Is DHCP bound to the appropriate vNIC's? Do you have a DHCP scope set up for the PXE network?

Comment: The DHCP server (and the new one) are both on a vDS. The DHCP NIC is IPed to be on the same network as the DHCP scope. The DHCP scope exists.

Comment: Is the DHCP scope activated? Try running a packet capture on the DHCP server and see if any DHCP traffic is coming in to it.

Comment: Yes, the DHCP scope is active. I will throw Wireshark on the server as soon as I can, and will confirm traffic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I manually added options 66 and 67 to the scope, and the PXE boot worked.

Comment: http://serverfault.com/questions/108593/dhcp-configuration-for-windows-deployment-services